# Overriding shorthand properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties, cil, accessor, mutators

My understanding is that when I create a shorthand property in c#, this translates to a field created for it once It's compiled.

```
class Hello {
  public bool Hi { set ; get ; }
}
```

My question is what happens if the shorthand property is virtual and then overridden:

```
class Hello {
  virtual public bool Hi { set ; get ; }
}

//The class and the property can't have the same name
//class Hi : Hello {
class Bonjour : Hello {
  override public bool Hi {
    set { }
    get { return true ; }
  }
}
```

I have overridden the virtual property entirely. Will this still generate a field when compiling the class Hi that I will not be able to access anymore?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the field will *still* be generated, as your `Hello` class *still* needs to be usable on its own.

If you want to access the underlying field from the `Bonjour` class, you can refer to the base property through `base.Hi`.

If you never intended for the `Hello` class to be usable on its own in the first place, make the class *and* the property `abstract`. No field will be generated then.

[Here's an example](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#MYGwhgzhAEASCmIQHtoG8BQ1oDcCWATgC4CuYI0ADiQEYh7DQ3LIUAKByl60E8R0ANzQA5vyHQAvhmkZQkGLDzQAXHEQp0WaMhzwCBPABN4VWvUbNW0Dly3ZsfAWinbsY59AL8SBAHbQRAQkpsLS2NKyYDQQQWDAAvJQ6kjIAIIx9tDRsQTxAtR0DEws7JzcLk4SHhKRGHLgyUoATKopKBkwmNi6+oYmZkWWpTblWY7iLuEONS7epP6BwaGuETL1QA==) of what happens when you compile and then decompile both cases.

Comment: I believe this to be true.

Comment: @Tony I've added a link which shows it's definitely true :)